# how do I zoom to normal text size in vs2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can not find any help on this issue in vs2008 help, Google, or SO.

**Scenario**:
I'm looking at a source file in vs2008 SP1; Windows 2003 Server SP2 Standard Edition, 1280x1024.

The irrelevant name of this file is index.aspx.

What is relevant is that the file has only 65 lines of code.
The print is unreadably small--less than 4 point.  It uses
less than a third of the vs2008 text window vertically and
less that a quarter of the vs2008 text window horizontally.

It's not just index.aspx; e.g. another file with 142 lines
only fills about 3/4 of the vs2008 text window vertically
and less that a quarter of the vs2008 text window horizontally.

**Possible cause**:
Probably, but not certainly, I found the equivalent of 
zoom in/zoom out such as one finds in products like
Microsoft Word.

However, I've explored many vs2008 toolbars and other
customization options and unfortunately I can not find
out how to get myself out of this mess.

**Window, Reset Window Layout** has no effect on the text size;
my tiny text size did not change.

**QUESTION**:  how do I zoom vs2008 text size in and out and back to normal size?

Comment: Zooming has been introduced in VS2010 - See http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/07/tips-and-tricks-zooming-in-the-vs-2010-editor.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try going to "Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors" and check the font -size used.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind a hotkey to change increase/decrease the font size.

http://www.cptloadtest.com/2009/01/26/Visual-Studio-Macro-Modify-Text-Editor-Font-Size.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  Those macros look very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Tools - Options - Fonts and Colors, change the font size for text.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 code zooming is standard, but I had to go back to Visual Studio 2008 that does not have code zooming, so I looked for a solution. It may be helpful for someone in the future.

"Tools → Options and drill down to Environment → Keyboard. The commands you are looking for are

-`Macros.Samples.Accessibility.DecreaseTextEditorFontSize`

-`Macros.Samples.Accessibility.IncreaseTextEditorFontSize`"

Set keyboard shortcuts for these two commands like you want.

Taken from:
[Visual Studio: Zoom in the Editor](http://choorucode.com/2011/06/03/visual-studio-zoom-in-the-editor/)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Anyway, thank you !